# New small Facebook oauth web dialog x old big classical oauth dialog

Tags: facebook-login, facebook-oauth

I want to get the full oauth old dialog from image #1 and I am getting the small new one on image #2

When I preview my dialog on developers.facebook.com/apps I get what I want, but when I load

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=123&redirect_uri=www I get the new small one.

It is not user related as the same url using a different client_id, from another app works fine. Is it the flow?

Thanks for any clue.

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

Comment: I don’t think that choice is yours. Facebook has “improved” the Auth dialog to what they think is more appealing and informative to users – and it’s important to have a consistent display of it across all apps, so as not to confuse users. The last time they started a new version of the Auth dialog (basically the one we had up until now), they gave developers a choice to “opt-in” for that using a migration setting for the time it took them to completely roll it out. But this time, I see no such thing in the docs.